# Redis mock cannot connect

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, jestjs, node-redis

In jest config

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./libs/redis/test/jest.setup.redis-mock.js'],
```

jest.setup.redis-mock.js:

```
jest.mock('redis', () => jest.requireActual('redis-mock'));
```

Basic test:

```
import { Redis } from '../../src';

describe('Redis', () => {
  it('test1', async () => {
    const redis = new Redis({ url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379' });
    await redis.init();
    expect(1).toBe(1);

    await redis.destroy();
  });
});
```

And my redis wrapper

```
import { createClient, RedisClientType } from 'redis';

class Redis {
  private _redis: RedisClientType

  constructor(private _configuration: IRedisConfiguration) {
    this._redisClient = createClient({
      url: this._configuration.url,
      username: this._configuration.userName,
      password: this._configuration.password
    });
  }

  public async init(): Promise<void> {
    await this._redisClient.connect();
  }

  public async destroy(): Promise<void> {
    await this._redisClient.disconnect();
  }
}
```

When I run test, I got:

```
TypeError: this._redisClient.connect is not a function
```

redis version from npm: 4.5.0
redis-mock: 0.56.3

**EDIT**

I commented connect and disconnect function, and now it doesn't throw any errors but looks like it doesn't work. This code:

```
await this._redisClient.SADD('myset', 'Hello');
const x = await this._redisClient.SMEMBERS('myset');
console.log('XXX', x);
```

Returns undefined

**EDIT 2**

```
const redismock = require('redis-mock');

(async function() {
  try {
    const client = redismock.createClient();
    await client.sadd('test', 'test');
    const members = await client.smembers('test');
    console.log(members);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error', error);
  }
})();
```

this simple code also returns undefined. Am i missing something to mock it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The `redis-mock` library does not implement all methods of the `redis` library. For example, [`.connect()`](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/79b0df8229b0c0e43b7da2a81eb382558946aa59/packages/client/lib/client/index.ts#L429) and [`.disconnect()`](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/79b0df8229b0c0e43b7da2a81eb382558946aa59/packages/client/lib/client/index.ts#L806) are not implemented. You can check the source code of [`RedisClient`](https://github.com/yeahoffline/redis-mock/blob/master/lib/client/redis-client.js#L110) class of `redis-mock`, `.connect()` and `.disconnect()` methods do not exist. That's why get the `TypeError: this._redisClient.connect is not a function`.

Unfortunately, the `redis-mock` library implements the redis methods using the [error-first callback pattern](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#error-first-callbacks), **not using promise.** That's why the `async/await` syntax does not work.

Besides, we should use `//@ts-nocheck` to disable the type check for TypeScript since the types/interfaces between `redis` and `redis-mock` libraries are not compatible. It will cause type errors at compiler time.

We have to use the callback to guarantee the execution order of asynchronous code.

The working example:

In order to access the `._redisClient` property, we need to make it as a public property.

`my-redis.ts`:

```
import { createClient, RedisClientType } from 'redis';

export class Redis {
    _redisClient: RedisClientType;

    constructor(private _configuration) {
        this._redisClient = createClient({
            url: this._configuration.url,
            username: this._configuration.userName,
            password: this._configuration.password,
        });
    }

    public async init(): Promise<void> {
        await this._redisClient.connect();
    }

    public async destroy(): Promise<void> {
        await this._redisClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

`my-redis.test.ts`:

```
//@ts-nocheck
import { Redis } from './my-redis';

describe('Redis', () => {
    it('test1', (done) => {
        const redis = new Redis({ url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379' });
        redis._redisClient.SADD('myset', 'Hello', (err, result) => {
            expect(result).toBe(1);
            redis._redisClient.SMEMBERS('myset', (err, result) => {
                expect(result).toEqual(['Hello']);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Test result:

```
 PASS  stackoverflow/75926628/my-redis.test.ts
  Redis
    ✓ test1 (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.505 s, estimated 2 s
```

package versions:

```json
"redis": "^4.6.7",
"redis-mock": "^0.56.3",
```